# jQuery pull currency without dollar sign

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I have a tag that has a price in it (ie. $150.00).  I want to use jQuery to pull only the text values without the dollar sign ($).

```
<div>
  $150.00
</div>
```

I want to output the above as `150.00`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the `$` character with an empty string:

```
var price = $("div").text().replace("$", "");
```

Note that in the case of your exact example (with that spacing) the blank spaces will not be removed. If you're going on to use the string as a number (via `parseFloat` for example) that won't matter, but if you're wanting to use it as text somewhere else, you may want to remove white space with jQuery's [`.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

**Update** - based on comments

`replace` returns a String. Once you have that string, you can parse it into a Number with `parseFloat` (or `parseInt`, but you're working with floating point numbers):

`var convertedToNumber = parseFloat(price);`

Now that you've got a number, you can perform mathematical operations on it:

`var percentage = convertedToNumber * 0.95;`

Comment: This works but now I need to modify my question, as I am trying to take that number and multiply it by .95 and shoot out an alert for testing ie. 
`var thePrice = $("div").text().replace("$", "");
 var isFivePercent = $((thePrice) * .95);
 alert(isFivePercent);`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do there, but you're wrapping a String in a jQuery object then trying to multiply the object by 0.95. Use `parseFloat` to parse the string into a Number, and don't put it in a jQuery object!

Comment: I am trying to display a discount price based on a div with a current price in it.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  One more..any way to get it so it when it displays it is only display 2 decimal places past number?

Comment: You can use the `toFixed` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 6):

Use of replace is better but I can suggest that you can remove any currency symbol from the string like

```
$ 150.00
Fr. 150.00
€ 689.00
```

I have tested for above three currency symbols .You can do it for others also.

```
var price = $("div").text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '');
```

Above regular expression will remove everything that is not a digit or a period.So You can get the string without currency symbol but in case of " Fr. 150.00 " if you console for output then you will get price as

```
console.log('price : '+price);

output = price : .150.00
```

which is wrong so you check the index of "." then split that and get the proper result.

```
if (price.indexOf('.') == 0) {
        price = parseFloat(price.split('.')[1]);
}else{
        price = parseFloat(price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `$('div').text().replace('$', '');` work your purposes?